# Highcharts heatmap specific drilldown on axis

Tags: highcharts, heatmap, axis, drilldown

I build a drillable heatmap with Highchart. It's working well but I need to enhance the capabilities of drilldown on it.
You can see the demo here : https://jsfiddle.net/vegaelce/7wc6t2ex/
I would like to be able to drill on the Y Axis and on the X Axis on specific series.
In the example, by clicking on "California" axis label, I would like the chart drill on 'California_years' drilldown serie.
In the same way, I'd like to be able to click on X-Axis, in the example, by clicking on '2015' label value, the chart would drill to 'States_2015' drilldown serie.

Notice that I use axe_x and axe_y values in each serie to change the axis of the chart on drilldown/drillup event :

```
    events:{
      drilldown: function(e) {
        var chart = this;
        chart.yAxis[0].update({
                type: 'category',
                categories: y_axes[e.seriesOptions.axe_y]
                        });
        chart.xAxis[0].update({
                type: 'category',
                categories: x_axes[e.seriesOptions.axe_x]
                        });
      },
      drillup: function(e) {
        var chart = this;
        chart.yAxis[0].update({
                type: 'category',
                categories: y_axes[e.seriesOptions.axe_y]
                        });
        chart.xAxis[0].update({
                type: 'category',
                categories: x_axes[e.seriesOptions.axe_x]
                        });
      }
    }
```

How can I achieve these features ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can check if `e.category` is defined, if it is, the drilldown was triggered by clicking on axis label. Next, you need to only bind the category with proper drilldown options. For example:

```
  chart: {
    type: 'heatmap',
    events: {
      drilldown: function(e) {
        if (typeof e.category !== 'undefined') {
          if (e.category === 0) {
            e.seriesOptions = this.options.drilldown.series[3];

          } else if (e.category === 3) {
            e.seriesOptions = this.options.drilldown.series[2]
          }
        }

        var chart = this;
        chart.yAxis[0].update({
          type: 'category',
          categories: y_axes[e.seriesOptions.axe_y]
        });
        chart.xAxis[0].update({
          type: 'category',
          categories: x_axes[e.seriesOptions.axe_x]
        });
      },
      ...
    }
  }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/186mdyfx/

Comment: Thanks I will test that. And how can I do the same thing on the X Axis ?

Comment: Hi @vegaelce, Sorry, I've missed that part of the question. Do you mean y-axis, right? You can add `customEvents` plugin and call custom drilldown on click on the axis label. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Lxjuzrt5/

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it helps !! But I have an anoying functioning : as soon as I insert the customEvents.js file, the first time I can click anywhere in the cell and it drills down correctly but when I go back and try again to drill, I must click specifically on the label of the cell to drill (I cannot click anywhere inside the cell). You can test in this example : https://jsfiddle.net/vegaelce/fhtsxwzu (just remove the customEvents plugin to see the difference). Have you a solution for that ? Thanks in advance

Comment: Ok, so you can add the click event on labels in a different way. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/4tnvpe5r/